# Binary Search Tree Questions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function to search a binary search tree for a value and return the TreeNode with the value.

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int value;
    struct TreeNode *pLeft, *pRight;
};
TreeNode* SearchTree(int query);
```

(For any node: `this->pLeft` contains nodes less the `this->value`, `this->pRight` contains nodes greater then `this->value`)

Comment: Alright. So what have you got so far?

Comment: The code what I have so far is already listed.

Comment: Please do not expect others to do your homework for you. If you're stuck with something, people here could give you some hints so that you can progress with your work. But, before that, you have to show that you know what you are doing and where your problem is.

Comment: You haven't really done a lot. Is it because you're struggling with it, or some other reason? If you're struggling, is there any particular area you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be something along the lines of:

```
treenode* SearchTree(int query, treenode* node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(query == node->value)
        return node;
    else if(query < node->value)
        return SearchTree(query, node->pLeft);
    else if(query > node->value)
        return SearchTree(query, node->pRight);
    else
        return NULL;
 }
```

if the node that you are at, has the value of what you are searching for, return the node address. if the current node value has less than what you are searching for, go down the right leaf, if current node value has more than what you are searching for, go down the left leaf. keep recursing until you hit an empty leaf, depending on your implementation on how the tree ends. But that's the general idea.

Comment: Two elementary errors here: 1. Your function has no termination criterion, in case query isn't in the tree. (I know you mention this in your commentary, but it's more important than that -- it should be on the code.) 2. You're not returning a value.

Comment: TonyK, ok I've changed the code to check termination criteria, he might have his own termination somehow, I'm just assuming now that all his leaf nodes will be NULL then. question asked to return the TreeNode with the value, not the value itself.

Comment: I simplified this code a bit.  It was missing some `return` statements and referred to `this` in places where it should have been `node`.

Comment: ah okay then. Thanks for the corrections, I just quickly whipped up something. Havent really touched c/c++ for a while now. I wasn't really meant to do a really complete answer for him. These answers can be found readily on google anyway..

Comment: That last 'else' shows a cynical lack of faith in the Peano axioms

Answer (score 0):

You solve this by using recursion.

- You need a terminating step.
- You'll also need the recursive step that checks a tree node and calls itself.

I'd suggest you use `NULL` as the return value when it is not found.